# how to insert data into sqlite using qt

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt4, qml

how to insert the data into `sqlite` using `qt`:

```
query = QSqlQuery("INSERT INTO customer_details (rationcard_num, aadharcard_num, name) 
    values('"+rationcard_num+"','"+aadharcard_num+"','"+name+"')");
```

Comment: What is the problem with that code?

Comment: I have provided a working example that strictly follows the official Qt docs. If it solves your problem (which I am sure it does) then please accept the answer. It will be helpful for future references.

Answer (score 5):

You can modify your code and make the query look like this, which I think will clarify your doubts:

*Preparing query statement*

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO customer_details(rationcard_num \
                 , aadharcard_num \
                 , name) \ 
                 VALUES(:rationcard_num \
                 , :aadharcard_num \
                 , :name); ");
```

*Bind values*

```
query.bindValue(":rationcard_num", your_value);
query.bindValue(":aadharcard_num", your_value);
query.bindValue(":name", your_value);
```

*DEBUGGING*

You can use `qDebug()` to find if your query is executable:

```
qDebug()<<query.exec()<<endl;
```

This will return true if data inserted and false otherwise

Comment: Note that you had a missing `:` in front of `name` in your `values (...)`. That could have been a problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably call [`exec()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#exec) on the query or call it directly with [`exec(const QString& query)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#exec). So for example you could do:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("INSERT INTO customer_details (rationcard_num, aadharcard_num, name)" 
            + "values('" + rationcard_num + "','" + aadharcard_num + "','" 
            + name + "')");
```

If however you want to use a prepared statement you would want to construct the query with a QSqlDatabase, call [`prepare(statement)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#prepare) on that and bind the values. For example:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (rationcard_num, aadharcard_num, name) "
               "VALUES (:rationcard_num, :aadharcard_num, :name)");
query.bindValue(":rationcard_num", rationcard_num);
query.bindValue(":aadharcard_num", aadharcard_num);
query.bindValue(":name", name);
query.exec();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("INSERT INTO customer_details (rationcard_num,aadharcard_num,name)VALUES('"+rationcard_num+"','"+aadharcard_num+"','"+name+")");
```

Comment: This has SQL injection attack written all over it, in the very least, unless you perform some serious integrity and validation checking, the user will be able to enter anything they want into the database.